# Spacy Displacy Manual is not working when manual=True

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am following the exact same code mentioned in the  Official Spacy Doc: https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers

```
from spacy import displacy

ex = {
    "text": "Welcome to the Bank of China.",
    "spans": [
        {"start_token": 3, "end_token": 6, "label": "ORG"},
        {"start_token": 5, "end_token": 6, "label": "GPE"},
    ],
    "tokens": ["Welcome", "to", "the", "Bank", "of", "China", "."],
}
html = displacy.render(ex, style="ent", manual=True)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 13>()
      3 from spacy import displacy
      5 ex = {
      6     "text": "Welcome to the Bank of China.",
      7     "spans": [
   (...)
     11     "tokens": ["Welcome", "to", "the", "Bank", "of", "China", "."],
     12 }
---> 13 html = displacy.render(ex, style="ent", manual=True)

File /data/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/displacy/__init__.py:52, in render(docs, style, page, minify, jupyter, options, manual)
     50 renderer = renderer(options=options)
     51 parsed = [converter(doc, options) for doc in docs] if not manual else docs
---> 52 _html["parsed"] = renderer.render(parsed, page=page, minify=minify).strip()
     53 html = _html["parsed"]
     54 if RENDER_WRAPPER is not None:

File /data/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/displacy/render.py:280, in EntityRenderer.render(self, parsed, page, minify)
    278         self.direction = settings.get("direction", DEFAULT_DIR)
    279         self.lang = settings.get("lang", DEFAULT_LANG)
--> 280     rendered.append(self.render_ents(p["text"], p["ents"], p.get("title")))
    281 if page:
    282     docs = "".join([TPL_FIGURE.format(content=doc) for doc in rendered])

KeyError: 'ents'
```

PS: Spacy Version : 2.2.4

What am I missing, how do i fix this?

Comment: spaCy 2.2.4 is over two years old, and v3 has been out over a year, so the docs refer to that. Can you upgrade spaCy?

Comment: My Organization is working on project that uses 2.2.4, I want to be able to integrate the above code with existing project

Comment: OK, in that case you should refer to the v2 docs. https://v2.spacy.io/

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the wrong doc version, thanks for the help!